# Can anyone help me with this program?

Tags: python

```
    class student:
def __init__(self,name,sub,mark):
    self.name=name
    self.sub=sub
    self.mark=mark
def on_kv_board(self):
    if (self.mark>=450):
        return True
    else:`enter code here`
        return False
students=[]
num_student=int(input("Enter the number of students appeared:"))
for entries in range(0,num_student):
name=input("Student name:")
sub=input("Subject in which "+name+" got the highest mark:")
mark=int(input("Total marks obtained/500:"))
if student(name,sub,mark).on_kv_board() is True:
    a=(student(name,sub,mark))
    students.append(a)
print(students)
```

> Whenever I print the students[] list with two inputs it gives me an output [Student.student object at 0x03784790, Student.student object at 0x037D61B0]

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? And please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: The code is not even indented. Please indent the code and what is the exact problem in running the code? Be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need to implement one method `__repr__`:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self,name,sub,mark):
        self.name=name
        self.sub=sub
        self.mark=mark
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"(Student:[{self.name}, {self.sub}, {self.mark}]) "
    def on_kv_board(self):
        if (self.mark>=450):
            return True
        else:
            return False
students=[]
num_student=int(input("Enter the number of students appeared:"))
for entries in range(0,num_student):
    name=input("Student name:")
    sub=input("Subject in which "+name+" got the highest mark:")
    mark=int(input("Total marks obtained/500:"))
if student(name,sub,mark).on_kv_board() is True:
    a=(student(name,sub,mark))
    students.append(a)

print(students)
```

output:

```
Enter the number of students appeared:1
Student name:123
Subject in which 123 got the highest mark:456
Total marks obtained/500:789
[(Student:[123, 456, 789]) ]
```

the `__repr__` is the function can format class output.